# Count how many row with last item is 1 or 0 in CSV file Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have CSV file like this:

```
2,1,2,3,1
23,3,2,22,0
2,2,11,2,0
1,2,2,1,1
    .
    .
44,3,3,44,0
2,2,11,2,0
```

Each row ended with 1 or 0, I want to count the prior probability for 1 or 0 by counting how many row with last item is 1 or 0 divide by total rows. How to solve it in python. Thank you.

Comment: Do post the code from your attempt

Comment: Make an attempt. You could use the `csv` module, or just read the lines counting them all and counting the ones ending in zero.  Then do the math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv

total = 0
zeros = 0
ones = 0
with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    for row in csv.reader(infile):
        total += 1
        if row[-1] == '0': zeros += 1
        if row[-1] == '1': ones += 1

# do some division to calculate priors
```